# Per-Document Word Count in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Spark (in Scala) and have been trying to figure out how to count all the the words on each line of a file. 
I am working with a dataset where each line contains a tab-separated document_id and the full text of the document

```
doc_1   <full-text>
doc_2   <full-text>
etc..
```

Here is a toy example I have in a file called doc.txt

```
doc_1   new york city new york state
doc_2   rain rain go away
```

I *think* what I need to do is transform into tuples containig

```
((doc_id, word), 1)
```

and then call reduceByKey() to sum the 1's. I wrote the following:

```
val file = sc.textFile("docs.txt")
val tuples = file.map(_.split("\t"))
            .map( x => (x(1).split("\\s+")
            .map(y => ((x(0), y), 1 ))   ) )
```

Which does give me the intermediate representation I think I need:

```
tuples.collect

res0: Array[Array[((String, String), Int)]] = Array(Array(((doc_1,new),1), ((doc_1,york),1), ((doc_1,city),1), ((doc_1,new),1), ((doc_1,york),1), ((doc_1,state),1)), Array(((doc_2,rain),1), ((doc_2,rain),1), ((doc_2,go),1), ((doc_2,away),1)))
```

But if call reduceByKey on tuples it produces an error

```
tuples.reduceByKey(_ + )
<console>:21: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[((String, String), Int)]]
              tuples.reduceByKey(_ + )
```

I can't seem to get my head around how to do this. I *think* I need to do a reduce on an array inside an array. I have tried many different things but like the above keep getting errors and making no progress. 
Any guidance / advice on this would be much appreciated.

Note: I know that there is a word count example on https://spark.apache.org/examples.html showing how to get counts for all of the words in a file. But that is for an entire input file. I am talking about getting counts per-document where each document is on a different line.

Comment: You've got an `RDD[Array[...]]`; you need a simple `RDD` with all your values in, which you could get by `flatMap(identity)`, and then you'll be able to `reduceByKey`. @Justin has a more complete answer, but that's the minimal change needed to make your program run.

Comment: @lmm Haha, I just reworked my solution to be something similar as the original answer did not make me happy, then I see this comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduceByKey` expects type `RDD[(K,V)]` whereas the instant you perform the `split` in the first `map`, you end up with an `RDD[Array[...]]`, which is not the type signature that is needed. You can rework your current solution as below...but it probably will not be as performant (read after the code for a rework using `flatMap`):

```
//Dummy data load
val file = sc.parallelize(List("doc_1\tnew york city","doc_2\train rain go away"))  

//Split the data on tabs to get an array of (key, line) tuples
val firstPass = file.map(_.split("\t"))

//Split the line inside each tuple so you now have an array of (key, Array(...)) 
//Where the inner array is full of (word, 1) tuples
val secondPass = firstPass.map(x=>(x(0), x(1).split("\\s+").map(y=>(y,1)))) 

//Now group the words and re-map so that the inner tuple is the wordcount
val finalPass = secondPass.map(x=>(x._1, x._2.groupBy(_._1).map(y=>(y._1,y._2.size))))
```

**Probably the better solution  vvvv :**

If you want to keep your current structure, then you need to change to using a `Tuple2` from the start and then using a `flatMap` after:

```
//Load your data
val file = sc.parallelize(List("doc_1\tnew york city","doc_2\train rain go away"))
//Turn the data into a key-value RDD (I suggest caching the split, kept 1 line for SO)
val firstPass = file.map(x=>(x.split("\t")(0), x.split("\t")(1)))
//Change your key to be a Tuple2[String,String] and the value is the count
val tuples = firstPass.flatMap(x=>x._2.split("\\s+").map(y=>((x._1, y), 1)))
```

Comment: My first answer was not satisfactory to me, so I rethought the problem and came up with a better one that is probably better all around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo on a VERY small dataset.

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("../README.md")
15/02/02 00:32:38 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(32792) called with curMem=45512, maxMem=278302556
15/02/02 00:32:38 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 32.0 KB, free 265.3 MB)
file: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ../README.md MappedRDD[7] at textFile at <console>:12

scala> val splitLines = file.map{ line => line.split(" ") } 
splitLines: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MappedRDD[9] at map at <console>:14

scala> splitLines.map{ arr => arr.toList.groupBy(identity).map{ x => (x._1, x._2.size) } }
res19: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = MappedRDD[10] at map at <console>:17

scala> val result = splitLines.map{ arr => arr.toList.groupBy(identity).map{ x => (x._1, x._2.size) } }
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = MappedRDD[11] at map at <console>:16

scala> result.take(10).foreach(println)

Map(# -> 1, Spark -> 1, Apache -> 1)
Map( -> 1)
Map(for -> 1, is -> 1, Data. -> 1, system -> 1, a -> 1, provides -> 1, computing -> 1, cluster -> 1, general -> 1, Spark -> 1, It -> 1, fast -> 1, Big -> 1, and -> 1)
Map(in -> 1, Scala, -> 1, optimized -> 1, APIs -> 1, that -> 1, Java, -> 1, high-level -> 1, an -> 1, Python, -> 1, and -> 2, engine -> 1)
Map(for -> 1, data -> 1, a -> 1, also -> 1, general -> 1, supports -> 2, It -> 1, graphs -> 1, analysis. -> 1, computation -> 1)
Map(for -> 1, set -> 1, tools -> 1, rich -> 1, Spark -> 1, structured -> 1, including -> 1, of -> 1, and -> 1, higher-level -> 1, SQL -> 2)
Map(GraphX -> 1, for -> 2, processing, -> 2, data -> 1, MLlib -> 1, learning, -> 1, machine -> 1, graph -> 1)
Map(for -> 1, Streaming -> 1, processing. -> 1, stream -> 1, Spark -> 1, and -> 1)
Map( -> 1)
Map(<http://spark.apache.org/> -> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Input file content:
    a b c d
    a b e f 
    h i j l
    m h i l

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local");
            JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

            JavaRDD<String> textFile = javaSparkContext.textFile("C:\\Users\\arun7.gupta\\Desktop\\Spark\\word.txt");

            /**Splitting the word with space*/
            textFile = textFile.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator());

            /**Pair the word with count*/
            JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> mapToPair = textFile.mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<>(w, 1));

            /**Reduce the pair with key and add count*/
            JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> reduceByKey = mapToPair.reduceByKey((wc1, wc2) -> wc1 + wc2);

            System.out.println(reduceByKey.collectAsMap());
            javaSparkContext.close();
        }

Output:
{e=1, h=2, b=2, j=1, m=1, d=1, a=2, i=2, c=1, l=2, f=1}
```